# Is the word 'lousy' used more often in the UK than in the US?

Tags: word-choice

It seems to be considered a peculiar word to use in the US (like 'queue' or 'spectacles' or 'pail').

And more generally, is there any resource I can use to compare how frequent any particular word is used in the UK vs the US?

Comment: [One way](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lousy%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+lousy%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clousy%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clousy%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: There are two senses of the word.  As an informal term meaning *bad*, I think of it as very typically American, though probably more common 50 years ago than now.  There is also the phrase *lousy with*, meaning filled or metaphorically infested with, as in *the shop is lousy with tourists*, which seems less common in the US and maybe is more common in the UK.

Comment: In addition to what @NateEldredge says, some people (in the US) may use "lousy" as a pseudo-adjective (I'm sure there's some technical term) to color one's speech (akin to the use of "f**king" by some people).  Eg, one might say "Set your lousy butt down and let's chat awhile."

Comment: [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) will do 'frequencies over time', but [beware](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu)

Answer (score 1):

Gotta disagree w/ the "not on the East Coast" disagreement. Older expressions seem to live longer in the New England States and "lousy with" is still quite common - meaning "infested". (And everybody there knows that it originated with a head-full of lice.) Ex: "Mrs. Vanderbilt was lousy with jewels." It is probably less common to hear it used in the more modern sense,(of "crappy") except where it might truly be accurate: "That motel room was lousy."

Answer (score 0):

Lousy as is described by Merriam Webster, "bad or poor: of poor quality" is used a fair amount in the US. I have only found the expression "lousy with" as referenced above in a blog written by a Canadian (Yarharlot.ca). For what it is worth, the first time I came across it being used literally, to refer to actual lice, in my childhood, was when I read one of the Laura Ingalls Wilder Little House books. Lice are more common in American childhoods today and it may well be used more frequently now.

Comment: I've never comprehended the purpose of the phrase "*for what it is worth*".

Comment: Google Ngrams shows _lousy with_ peaking in the 1940's in both US and British use. They don't seem to have a Canadian corpus.

Comment: In Canada (at least in my experience) the two uses are pronounced differently.  "lousy with" has a soft S and "lousy" (as in "lousy day") has a hard "S".

Answer (score 0):

It's more common in the US than UK overall.

In the UK, it seems to be used almost specifically to describe feeling under the weather, like "I feel pretty lousy". To say "it was a lousy song" would be unusual here.

I think I remember a marketing campaign for something like cold syrup that used the word, and it seemed to just catch on in that context. *I think*.

Comment: That's not true anymore. People like me brought this word over and now everyone around me all over the country are using this word with wild abandon. The word is extremely popular in the US now. "Have a lousy day, with some lousy friends, with a lousy future."

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree. "Lousy" is not used very often in the US. At least not on the east coast. We typically use "crappy" or "sucks" instead.

For example - That movie was crappy or that movie sucked!

Every once in a while, someone might say they feel lousy when they are sick but for the most part, people say they feel like crap.

"Lousy" was popular in the 1950's and 60's when we were still akin to using "the King's English". Our cultures and slang have intertwined so we use as many adjectives as we can. We don't just rely on one. We are also known to make up a few new ones.

We don't say have a lousy day. I have only heard that on Brit TV sitcoms. Sounds weird, I don't even know how to take that. Generally, we wish our friends a good day- like the Aussies- sans the "mate".